# Access to XMLHttpRequest site has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: .net

Continuing to get a CORS error when calling my api.  I've tried everything I've seen online.  For some reason this is still erroring.  What am I missing here???

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/api/Admin/...' from origin 'https://site.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "_myAllowSpecificOrigins",
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("*")
                          .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                          .AllowAnyHeader()
                          .AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("_myAllowSpecificOrigins");

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```